# How to Authorize rest APIs using token from another service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt, authorization

I have created jwt token using spring boot in one service let's call it Authorization service and I have one more service user service.
Now I want to access the user service resources using token which is generated by Authorization service, now how can I use that token in user service to access the APIs.

Any reference or any comments.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filters to intercept the call before it reaches the controllers. In the filter, you have to send that token to the authorization service to check if the token is valid and if it is then let the request pass to the controllers.